# MySQL : Select all the rows except those having the specified values in columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have data in my table that looks like the following.

```
 dcno | etype | debit | credit |
------+-------+-------+--------+
  1   | sale  | 1200  | 1000   |
  2   | sale  | 1000  | 600    |
  3   | sale  | 1100  | 9001   |
  1   | purc  | 1274  | 1281   |
  4   | sale  | 1119  | 2811   |
  6   | sale  | 2345  | 233    |
  2   | purc  | 4467  | 121    |
  3   | sale  | 8885  | 1214   |
```

What I want is a query that doesnt consider the row 
having the specified `dcno` and `etype`. For example if I specify that I don't want the row having the dcno
of 1 and etype of sale it should return the following:

```
 dcno | etype | debit | credit |
------+-------+-------+--------+
  2   | sale  | 1000  | 600    |
  3   | sale  | 1100  | 9001   |
  1   | purc  | 1274  | 1281   |
  4   | sale  | 1119  | 2811   |
  6   | sale  | 2345  | 233    |
  2   | purc  | 4467  | 121    |
  3   | sale  | 8885  | 1214   |
```

I have tried with the following

```
SELECT  *
FROM    pledger
WHERE   dcno <> 1 AND pledger.etype <> 'sale'
```

but that didn't work (as expected). Can anyone please tell me how may I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by does not work as expected?

Comment: Try TRIM(pledger.etype)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dfef1/4 Weird.

Comment: Are you try code "SELECT  * FROM    pledger WHERE pledger.etype <> 'sale'"? Doesnt work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `or`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    pledger
WHERE   dcno <> 1 OR pledger.etype <> 'sale'
```

Boolean logic says that `NOT (X AND Y)` is logically equivalent to `NOT X OR NOT Y`.  So, `NOT (dcno = 1 AND etype = 'sale')` is `dcno <> 1 OR etype <> 'sale'`.  Note:  this doesn't take `NULL` into account, but that is not relevant here.

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2fe1/5)

Comment: But this would exclude all record where etype != 'sale' _and_ all records where dcno != 1. That's not what he wants, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Sherlock . . . I'll let you think about that.  You should work out the truth tables for the different statements to see how they work (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table).  All the negatives do get confusing.